# cannot find requested object - System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Tags: cryptography, azure-functions, x509certificate2

My code is :

```
var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(req.RequestUri.Query);
string certificate = = query.Get("issuerCertificate");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(certificate);
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which runtime are you using ?

Comment: I am using azure function. http://localhost:7071 only

Comment: Dude, that's not runtime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview

Comment: I am using azure function version 1.x only

Comment: Is the certificate file a PFX? Azure Functions probably don’t have a user profile loaded, so you’d have to load them with the EphemeralKeySet flag.

Comment: @bartonjs This is .cer file.

Answer (score 0):

While sending certificate from query string param, inside certificate in between some spaces was there. So i remove spaces via added application/json. Now my certificate running fine.